# How are GUI frameworks actually developed

Tags: cocoa, qt, user-interface, gtk

I worked mainly in web development but occasionally do some C/C++ or Java programming. I am very curious how these frameworks actually produce the graphics used in their GUI. Were the GUI elements (title bar, window frame, status bar, buttons, etc...) designed by a designer in Photoshop then a developer adds that graphic to the framework? Or do the developers actually build the elements programatically with the direction of a designer?

If someone could give me an overview that would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question, Lark ! Since we're in Qt Framework branch, I'll tell you how its done in Qt, but I'm sure you can apply to similar frameworks or libraries like GTK, etc.

So Qt started a framework that would provide one API for a variety of platforms making it very easy to port your applications from one platform to another while providing **native** look and feel on those platform. So for example on MacOSX a push button would have this blue Aqua style while on Windows XP it would look like a button on Windows platform. Trolltech put a lot of effort and did a great job on making the GUI look native. So how it works ? Well, all Qt widgets use QStyle and its derivatives to render themselves. Depending on the style, a widget would look differently. All the standard widgets follow the guides of those platforms they are designed for. There are probably some small graphics designer work behind that, but I believe its not that significant. The main source of the look and feel is the platform guides that describe how UI elements on those platforms should look like and their behavior.

But Qt has been developing very fast and the trolls came with a very promising technology called [Qt Quick](http://qt.nokia.com/qtquick/). Its an amazing technology which allows designers and developers tightly work together providing the best UI. Its highly oriented on using artwork made in Photoshop, GIMP or similar tools in the code. And its much easier to use mock ups from designers with Qt Quick than with C++/Qt cause Qt Quick is initially designed for that.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Barbaris! So does the Qt framework actually do the drawing of the elements instead of pulling in graphic files (.jpg, .png, etc...)?

Comment: Yes, it does the rendering using QPainter which in its turn calls platform dependent primitive functions like drawRect rendering the parts of each UI element. Although, as I said, with Qt Quick you can take advantage of developers-designers cooperation, substituting most of paint methods that you do using the API by using artwork.

Comment: Are the platform primitive functions (such as drawRect) a part of the OS that the Qt app is running on? So for example: Windows 7 has a drawRect that draws a "Windows" style rectangle and OS X has a drawRect that draws a "Mac OS X" style rectangle. If this is the case, would the platform functions (drawRect) actually draw the pixels on the screen using their own styles?

Comment: I don't believe that the outcome of "drawRect" is different on any of the platforms in terms what you visually see. It would be a rectangle with a line width of X, color Y and dimensions AxB. Qt uses those APIs to render its widgets integrating QStyle API to provide developers an advantage of changing the small details of how the elements look like.

Comment: What you mentioned is probably something more high level. I don't really know the platforms APIs for rendering the UI elements but I believe that it may exist some methods that indeed provide some "MacOSX looking" frame or something. I believe that Qt's code is implemented in a way to take advantage of it only if necessary.

Comment: Barbaris thank you for all your help! Your answer and comments has given me a better understanding. I also found this nice little wiki page that shed even more light: http://wiki.osdev.org/GUI

Comment: It should be mentioned that the QT way is a dead end. The Theming API's have largely deprecated on MacOSX and Windows7 and it even never worked before. QT application look everything else then native. And with more complex GUI's (Animations for example) it's also not possible to follow this way. The world belongs to native OS vendor and WxWidget like toolkits.

Answer (score 1):

The basic low level functionality of most GUI frameworks is quite old, the result of a great deal of very hard work by earlier developers working with primitives - literally drawing things on terminal screens, etc, at very low levels, using C or Assembler. Slowly, libraries for abstraction of these processes, and frameworks and class hierarchies for refining them and organizing come into being. All Linux GUI's (in fact, nearly all contemporary GUI frameworks) are based on [**XWindows**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), for example:

> X originated at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT) in
>   1984. The protocol version has been X11 since September 1987....X primarily defines protocol and graphics primitives - it deliberately
>   contains no specification for application user-interface design, such
>   as button, menu, or window title-bar styles. Instead, application
>   software – such as window managers, GUI widget toolkits and desktop
>   environments, or application-specific graphical user interfaces –
>   define and provide such details. As a result, there is no typical X
>   interface and several different desktop environments have become
>   popular among users.

See more there, for some good information about this topic.